# How to play music again when returing to main activity

Tags: android, android-intent

What I would like to achieve is to stop the music when I go to my 2nd activity from my main activity (this works and the music does stop) But when I press the back button to go back to the main activity the music doesn't seem to start again.   How can I make it to start again or if possible pause to music when going to the 2nd activity and resume when going back to the main activity.

Here is my code where the music stops when going to the next activity but doesn't play when going back to the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public static MediaPlayer player;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music_a);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.start();

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        player.stop();


    }
    });

}

     protected void onPause() {
        if (this.isFinishing()){ 
            player.stop();
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BYE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService (Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
          ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity; 
          if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            player.stop();
          }
          else {
          }
        }
        super.onPause();
      }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

And here is my 2nd activity (do I need to put something here as well?)

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen);
}

 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `onResume` on your First Activity to continue playing music

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
     // stop the music
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    // play the music here
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks,  that makes sense, but where do I call the onResume in my main activity?

Comment: What I have done is this  "@Override
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        player.start();"

Comment: In my opinion you have to add even this: `...onResume() { super.onResume(); if(player!=null)player.start();...`

Answer (score 0):

just remove your code to play from oncreate and start playing song in onResume

```
try {
        if (player != null) {
            player.start();
        } else {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.meintenu);
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
edit:
```

write this in your button click

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

  startActivity(intent);

  player.stop();

  player.release();

  player=null;
```

Comment: Have tried this as well but doesn't seem to start the music when going back to the main activity.

Comment: r u getting any error in log cat..just try to debug and see if it actuly goes to play..

Comment: see my edited answer ..i have tried it..and it is working good for me :)

Answer (score 0):

pause Your music when you go to next activity and get the current position of the music

```
    homeMusic.pause();
    position=homeMusic.getCurrentPosition();
```

then add `onRestart` method,

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    homeMusic.seekTo(position);
    homeMusic.start();
    homeMusic.setLooping(true);

}
```